# Как найти все числа из строки

Tags: javascript

Помогите вытащить все числа из строки

```
let inputData = '1, -5.8 или 10, хотя 34 + -5.3 и 73'; 

function getString(str) {
    let result = str.split(', ')
    console.log(result)
}

getString(inputData)
```

Comment: parseInt(a.match(/\d+/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения

```js
let inputData = '1, -5.8 или 10, хотя 34 + -5.3 и 73'; 

function getString(str) {
    let result = str.match(/(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/g).map(v => +v);
    console.log(result)
}

getString(inputData)
```

Comment: `.map(v => +v);` ←→ `.map(Number);` или так)